# mysql_real_escape_string in PHP 5.2 and 5.3?

Tags: php, content-management-system, escaping, ckeditor

I made a simple content editor which utilizes CKEditor. As of currently, it works fine on my local web server but when I upload it to my remote server, it goes out of whack.

Below is a sample output from my local server.

```
<img alt="" src="usrfiles/default_placeholder.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; " />
```

And below is the output that my remote server returns.

```
&lt;img alt=&quot;\&amp;quot;\&amp;quot;&quot; data-cke-saved-src=&quot;\&quot; src=&quot;\&amp;quot;usrfiles/default_placeholder.png\&amp;quot;&quot; style=&quot;\&amp;quot;width:&quot; 150px;=&quot;&quot; height:=&quot;&quot; \&quot;=&quot;&quot;&gt;
```

I didn't do any modifications to the code I use locally and remotely. Aside from of course, changing the database pointers (server, db name, username, etc). My only suspect right now is the **mysql_real_escape_string()** which I use upon submission of the text.

My local server uses PHP version 5.3.6 and my remote server uses PHP version 5.2.13. Is there a difference with the **mysql_real_escape_string()** behavior on these two versions?

**EDIT**
In reply to CodeCaster,
"Please provide more context to where this "output" comes from. How is it stored in the database, how do you store and retreive it, how do you view it. It most probably has nothing to do with mysql_real_escape_string() as it has with magic quotes and htmlentities."

The output comes from an SQL query. It is stored in the database as TEXT data type. It is stored and retrieved both via PHP SQL queries. I use mysql_real_escape_string() while I INSERT or UPDATE the data. On my local server, I can INSERT it with a query enclosed inside mysql_real_escape_string() and retrieve it without any alterations to the stored data and it outputs the data as HTML code just fine. On the remote server, this system breaks.

Comment: I havent really experienced any difference between PHP 5.2.13 or PHP 5.3.6. However, I'm pretty positive that is the problem.

Comment: Please provide more context to where this "output" comes from. How is it stored in the database, how do you store and retreive it, how do you view it. It most probably has nothing to do with mysql_real_escape_string() as it has with magic quotes and htmlentities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just wild guessing, but it can be that on you production server magic_quotes are enabled, so whenever you retrieve content from the database backslashes are automatically added and CKEditor, when receiving an html full of slashes, go nuts and place the html *as source* inside its content, and therefore applies html encoding.

The best solution would be turning magic_quotes off. A solution using PHP:

```
ini_set( 'magic_quotes_gpc', 0 );
```

While using htaccess:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

To remove the current ones just apply `stripslashes($string)` and save back (after disabling magic_quotes, I mean)

Comment: Hi, do I need to call the code ini_set on each page? Or do I only need to call it once for every person that visits the website?

Comment: If you have a front-controller approach, place it in that page; or call it in sensible locations, it really depends on your design. ELse try the htaccess approach, so you don't need to repeat it over and over. Or modify your php.ini directly, if you can.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the .htaccess but I'm not really experienced with editing it. Do I have to place the .htaccess on every subfolder? Or would the root folder do?